# controlling which blobs are indexed azure search

Tags: json, azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-blob-storage

I was wondering if it was possible to index specific blobs, based on their name.

For example how can I index "only" blobs named transactions.json?

Currently when I put the extension `.json` as the value to indexFileNameExtension, the indexer, indexes all .json file, and this makes my index have documents where it's fields are all null.

Is there any way to specify the filename including the extension?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Azure Search does not support using something like a regex or a wildcard to filter the blobs.

You have several options:

1. If you can control the blob layout, you can put the blobs you want to index into a separate virtual folder, and point your datasource to that folder.
2. If you can control the blob names, you can use a different extension for blobs that you don't want to index.
3. You can add `AzureSearch_Skip` : `"true"` metadata to the blobs you don't want to index.

If none of these options work for you, please add a suggestion on [Azure Search UserVoice site](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search) so others with similar requirements can vote for it and help us prioritize this feature.

Comment: So my blobs are seperated into virtual folder.

For example: `containerName/containerName-Guid.NewGuid()/init/init.json`

I have been trying to add `containerName/containerName-Guid.NewgGuid()/init` as a value under the pathPrefix parameter in the DataSource.AzureBlobStorage().

However it is not working.

I have also tried to only add the `init` i.e. the last directory in which my blob resides in. Still didn't work. Any Idea?

Comment: Path prefix should include virtual folder *relative* to the container. For example, `"containerName-abc-def/init"`. And no, you cannot just add `"init"`, it should the path starting at the root of the container.